# ¿Cómo obtener la diferencia de días entre dos fechas en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Necesito encontrar la diferencia de días que hay entre dos fechas, las cuales tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
// el formato de estas es (yyyy-mm-dd)
// Corresponden al 12 de julio del 2016 hasta el 1 de agosto del 2016
var fechaInicio = '2016-07-12';
var fechaFin    = '2016-08-1';
```

Si intento restarlas tal cual las tengo allí, el resultado es `NaN`. ¿Cómo podría resolverlo?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solución simple, para manipulación de fechas en JavaScript usa [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```js
var fecha1 = moment('2016-07-12');
var fecha2 = moment('2016-08-01');

console.log(fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'days'), ' dias de diferencia');
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

El método [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) te permite hallar la diferencia en cualquier unidad y la sintáxis es

```
moment.diff(moment, 'intervalo')
```

Para calcular lo mismo pero en horas

```js
var fecha1 = moment('2016-07-12');
var fecha2 = moment('2016-08-01');

console.log(fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'hours'), ' horas de diferencia');
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: recibo un `Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined`.

Comment: @rnd Estás importando la librería moment.js ?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo me refiero al stacksnippet.

Comment: Super @devconcept me funciono, Muchas gracias!

Comment: Valeep! Disculpa @rnd :)

Comment: aparentemente fue un problema local, disculpe la irrupcion sr.

Answer (score 30):

Puedes obtener los milisegundos entre las dos fechas y pasarlo a días :

```js
var fechaInicio = new Date('2016-07-12').getTime();
var fechaFin    = new Date('2016-08-01').getTime();

var diff = fechaFin - fechaInicio;

console.log(diff/(1000*60*60*24) );
                 // (1000*60*60*24) --> milisegundos -> segundos -> minutos -> horas -> días
```

Comment: excelente me funciono, lo necesitaba en años así que hice la división por 31536000000 que es el equivalente en años en mili segundos.

Answer (score 8):

Obtienes la diferencia en milisegundos y lo pasas a días.

```js
var date_1 = new Date('2015-2-15');
var date_2 = new Date('2015-3-13');

var day_as_milliseconds = 86400000;
var diff_in_millisenconds = date_2 - date_1;
var diff_in_days = diff_in_millisenconds / day_as_milliseconds;

console.log( diff_in_days );
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta opcion solo funciona si el formato de le fecha viene yy-mm-dd
en caso de que venga formato dd-mm-yy
habría que armar la fecha

```
var fechaInicio = $("#txt_fecha_desde_filtro").val().split("-");
var fechaFin = $("#txt_fecha_hasta_filtro").val().split("-");
var fechadesde = new Date(fechaInicio[2], fechaInicio[1]-1, fechaInicio[0]).getTime();
var fechahasta = new Date(fechaFin[2], fechaFin[1]-1, fechaFin[0]).getTime();    

var dias = fechahasta - fechadesde;
    var diff_ =dias/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    console.log(diff_);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Si con Moment.js lo puedes hacer

```js
(function()
{
  // instantiate a moment object
  var NowMoment = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  var Date =  '2018-09-06';
  
  // display value of moment object in #displayMoment div
  var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('displayMoment');
  eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = moment().diff(moment(Date), 'days');
  
  var eDisplayDate = document.getElementById('displayDate');
  eDisplayDate.innerHTML = NowMoment;
  
  var eDisplayOtherDate = document.getElementById('displayOtherDate');
  eDisplayOtherDate.innerHTML = Date;
})();
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<h2>HOY</h2>
<div id="displayDate"></div>

<h2>Otra Fecha</h2>
<div id="displayOtherDate"></div>

<h2>Diferencia en dias</h2>
<div id="displayMoment"></div>
```