# Obtener meses dentro de un rango de fechas en php

Tags: php

Hola quién me ayuda a obtener meses dentro de un rango de fechas ejemplo

```
$fechaRegistro="2017-07-21";
$fechaCorte="2017-11-21";
```

Quiero obtener los meses desde `$fechaRegistro` hasta `$fechaCorte`

He programado lo siguiente:

```
 Function contarMeses($a){
      $f1 = new DateTime( $a[0]);
      $f2 = new DateTime($a[1]);
      $d = $f1->diff($f2);
      $m = ($d->y * 12)+$d->m;
      Return $m;
    }

   function calculaFecha($a) { 
     $modo = ($a[0] == "months")? "months" : $a[0];
     $valor = $a[1];
     $fecha_inicio = strtotime($a[2]);
     $calculo = strtotime("$valor $modo","$fecha-inicio");
     Return date("Y-m-d",$calculo);
   }


  function verMeses($a){
      $f1 = $a[0];
      $f2 = $a[1];
      $countMeses = contarMeses(array($f1,$f2));

     $m = "";
     For($i = 0; $i < $countMeses ; $i++){
          $m .= calculaFecha( array("" , $i+1 , $f1)."<br>";
       }
       Echo $m;
      }

    verMeses(
        array(
            "2017-07-21",
             "2017-11-21"
        )
     );
```

Comment: ¿En JavaScript o en PHP? Solo puedes preguntar una cosa a la vez. Usa el buscador, la en JavaScript [ya tiene respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22073/como-obtener-la-diferencia-de-dias-entre-dos-fechas-en-javascript).

Comment: ¿Por qué algunos nombres de funciones están capitalizados? PHP distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas y eso hará que tu código falle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que esta función te va a servir. ( lo deje un una sola )

```
  function verMeses($a){

   $f1 = new DateTime( $a[0] );
   $f2 = new DateTime( $a[1] );

  // mostrara las fechas
  echo "valor f1 : " . $f1->format('d-m-Y') . "\n";
  echo "valor f2 : " . $f2->format('d-m-Y') . "\n";

  // obtener la diferencia de fechas
  $d = $f1->diff($f2);
  $difmes =  $d->format('%m');

  echo " Cantidad de meses " . $difmes . "\n";

  $impf = $f1;
  for($i = 1; $i <= $difmes; $i++){
      // despliega los meses
      $impf->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
      echo  $impf->format('d-m-Y') . " - " .$i.  "\n";
  }
}

 verMeses(  array(   "2017-07-21",   "2017-11-22" )    );
```

Comment: Excelente amigo espero que esta pregunta y tu respuesta ayuden a otro

Answer (score 0):

ok, edito mi respuesta. Probá con esto:

```
$f1 = new DateTime('2017-07-21');
    $f2 = new DateTime('2017-11-21');

    $cant_meses = $f2->diff($f1);
    $cant_meses = $cant_meses->format('%m'); //devuelve el numero de meses entre ambas fechas.
    $listaMeses = array($f1->format('Y-m-d'));

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $cant_meses; $i++) {

        $ultimaFecha = end($listaMeses);
        $ultimaFecha = new DateTime($ultimaFecha);
        $nuevaFecha = $ultimaFecha->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
        $nuevaFecha = $nuevaFecha->format('Y-m-d');

        array_push($listaMeses, $nuevaFecha) ;

    }
```

debug($listaMeses); die;

```
array(
(int) 0 => '2017-07-21',
(int) 1 => '2017-08-21',
(int) 2 => '2017-09-21',
(int) 3 => '2017-10-21',
(int) 4 => '2017-11-21'
```

)

Comment: Ok voy a probar tu lógica

Comment: Probando tu código obtengo es la cantidad de meses dentro del rango de fechas pero la lógica es que meses hay dentro de las fechas si $f1="2017-07-21"; $f2="2017-11-21";          se tienen que mostrar los meses dentro de esas dos fechas que de el resultado así                   2017-07-21,                                                      2017-08-21,                                                      2017-09-21,                                                        2017-10-21,                                                       2017-11-21

Comment: hice una edición en la respuesta. Ojalá te ayude. Cualquier duda comentame.