# Restar fechas en js

Tags: javascript, date

Hola quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer una resta de dos objetos **date**. Tengo una variable fecha de nacimiento y le quiero restar el día actual con fin de obtener el los **años** de diferencia ...

```js
    var f = new Date();
    var xf = (f.getDate() + "/" + (f.getMonth() +1) + "/" + f.getFullYear());
    var xy = 1981-11-17;
    var x = xf - xy; //¿se puede algo así?
      document.write(x);
```

puedo hacer algo así???

Comment: En esta pregunta de SOes tienes varias opciones de cómo hacerlo: [¿Cómo obtener la diferencia de días entre dos fechas en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22073/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-la-diferencia-de-d%C3%ADas-entre-dos-fechas-en-javascript). Recuerda siempre leer la [documentación oficial](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) del lenguaje que usas, a veces la respuesta está ahí mismo.

Comment: @quinqui hay una diferencia de la pregunta, el quiere saber el resultado de la resta , no la diferencia que hay entre las fechas, igual hay que esperar que aparezca

Comment: @JackNavaRow Diferencia y resta son sinónimos

Comment: diferencia entre dos fechas te devolvera dia, cuando restas fechas te retornara una nueva fecha.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Puedes usar también el siguiente modo, a través de getTime que a
>   partir de la fecha 1970/01/01 calcula los milisegundos pasados y con
>   la divisón que muestro obtienes los dias de diferencia entre una fecha
>   y otra

```js
let fecha1 = new Date('2016/08/12');
let fecha2 = new Date()

let resta = fecha2.getTime() - fecha1.getTime()
console.log(Math.round(resta/ (1000*60*60*24)))
```

> 60 seg que tiene un minuto * 60 minutos que tiene una hora * 24 hrs
>   que posee regularmente un día.
>
> la multuplicación por 1000 es para reducir tres cantidades al momento
>   final del resultado

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar la libreria moment.js

Es muy facil de utilizar y te ayuda con todos estos calcluos.

https://momentjs.com

Por ejemplo pudes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var a = moment().subtract(1, 'day');
var b = moment().add(1, 'day');
```

Saludos!

Comment: Si recomiendas una librería, procura poner unos ejemplos de uso, así contribuyes a una solución directa. Saludos.

Comment: @gugadev Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

si sumas o restas fechas debe ser en su formato, tambien puedes sumar/restar dias

```js
var f = new Date();
var xy = new Date("1981-11-17");
var x = new Date(f.getDate() - xy.getDate());
document.write(x);
//sumando dias
f.setDate(f.getDate() + 3); 
console.log(f);
//restando dias
x.setDate(x.getDate() - 3 );
console.log(x);
```