# Retornar datos desde MongoDB Atlas con tiempo de una hora atrás

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Tengo este campo en `collection` dentro de una base de datos en *MongoDB Atlas*.

```
created_at : 2019-10-09T10:55:00.202+00:00
```

¿Cómo puedo crear la *query* en *API Node Express* para que retorne datos por horas, según el campo `created_at`?

Por ejemplo una hora antes de este momento.

Lo solucioné haciendo esto, donde -3 es el UTC local:

```
var now = new Date();
var ago = new Date();
ago.setHours(now.getHours() - 3 - hour_range);
mymodel.find({device: req.params.device_id, created_at: {$gte : ago, $lt : now} }).exec(function (err, measures) {
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json({
        message: 'listing...',
        data: measures
    });
});
```

Comment: Hola. No esta muy claro lo que quieres hacer. Te esta devolviendo mal la hora?, no te esta devolviendo la hora? Como estas consultando la base de datos?

Comment: Measure.find() {} Necesito hacer consulta por rango de horas. Ahora solo sé que esto funciona manualmente created_at: {$gte : '2019-11-29T08:03:53.915Z', $lt : 2019-11-29T12:03:53.915Z

Comment: Las soluciones hay que ponerlas en la sección de respuestas, no en la pregunta, aunque eso tampoco parece la solución. Tampoco se entiende muy bien la pregunta.

Comment: es la solución, retorna datos en un rango de horas desde el momento de la consulta, de acuerdo al device consultado. La solución la encontré como esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184546/mongodb-date-range-query-for-past-hour

Answer (score 1):

Según comentas, lo que se me ocurre es agrupar los documentos en base a la hora, te muestro una posible solución:

- Datos de entrada de ejemplo:

---

```
[
  {
    "info": "uno",
    "created_at": ISODate("2016-04-30T13:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "info": "dos",
    "created_at": ISODate("2016-04-30T14:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "info": "tres",
    "created_at": ISODate("2016-04-30T05:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "info": "cuatro",
    "created_at": ISODate("2016-04-30T05:00:00Z"),
  }
]
```

- Query de MongoDB:

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $hour: "$created_at" // Identificador unico
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT" // Añade todos los documentos con esa hora en un campo 'data'
      }
    }
  }
])
```

- Resultados:

---

```
[
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
        "created_at": ISODate("2016-04-30T05:00:00Z"),
        "info": "tres"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
        "created_at": ISODate("2016-04-30T05:00:00Z"),
        "info": "cuatro"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 13,
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "created_at": ISODate("2016-04-30T13:00:00Z"),
        "info": "uno"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 14,
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
        "created_at": ISODate("2016-04-30T14:00:00Z"),
        "info": "dos"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

- Filtrado por horas:

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            $hour: "$created_at" // Identificador unico
          },
          data: {
            $push: "$$ROOT" // Añade todos los documentos con esa hora en un campo 'data'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
            _id: 5 //Filtramos por el campo donde se agrupan las horas
        }
      }
    ])
```

- Resultado:

---

```
   [
      {
        "_id": 5,
        "data": [
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
            "created_at": ISODate("2016-04-30T05:00:00Z"),
            "info": "tres"
          },
          {
            "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
            "created_at": ISODate("2016-04-30T05:00:00Z"),
            "info": "cuatro"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

- Query con fecha parseada en un campo adicional (Editado):

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
          {
            $addFields: { //Añade un campo 'convertedDate'
              convertedDate: { $toDate: "$created_at" } //Tranforma el campo 'created_at' en un formato fecha
            }
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: {
                $hour: "$convertedDate" // Identificador unico
              },
              data: {
                $push: "$$ROOT" // Añade todos los documentos con esa hora en un campo 'data'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $match: {
                _id: 5 //Filtramos por el campo donde se agrupan las horas
            }
          }
        ])
```

Espero que esta posible solución te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: ReferenceError: ISODate is not defined

Comment: Si hago la consulta de esta forma puedo filtrar por rango de horas : created_at: {$gte : '2019-11-29T08:03:53.915Z', $lt : 2019-11-29T12:03:53.915Z, pero no sé como lograr que lo haga automaticamente. Así como $gte : Date() - 3 horas $lt Date().now

Comment: Para la diferencia entre fechas puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/154378/33391)

Comment: @asterix pensaba que estarias trabajando con fechas en la base de datos pero según tu comentario estas con String. Para este caso tienes dos pasos, una seria parsear toda tu DB a Date (te lo recomiendo para trabajar con fechas en un futuro) o añadir un campo con la fecha pareada y trabajar con ese nuevo campo. Te edito la solución para que puedas ver como.

Comment: trabajo con fechas, era solo una prueba de comparación. El servidor mongodb Atlas al recibir el dato lo guarda con UTC +0