# Resta de fechas en JS

Tags: javascript, date

Solicitar una fecha y que me devuelva la diferencia en días, meses y años
que hay entre la fecha actual y la fecha introducida.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento para coger la fecha actual:

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
}
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
}
var today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
document.getElementById("DATE").value = today;

function mostrarFecha() {
    alert(today);
}
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22073/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-la-diferencia-de-d%C3%ADas-entre-dos-fechas-en-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar momentjs y especificamente el plugin moment pricise range,
te dejo un ejemplo de como lo harías, como resultado te devuelve un objecto con los valores que necesitarás posteriormente lo puedes formatear.

```js
var m1 = moment('2011-01-01 12:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var m2 = moment('2014-02-03 15:04:05','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var diff = moment.preciseDiff(m1, m2, true);
console.log(diff)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment-precise-range-plugin@1.3.0/moment-precise-range.min.js"></script>
```