# Como puedo calcular los dias entre dos fechas de forma dinamica?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datetime

como puedo hacer para calcular los dias entre dos fechas de forma dinamica.
Tengo un formulario con 2 input de tipo date, en donde el usuario carga en el primer input la fecha en que quiere salir de vacaciones, y en otro input la fecha en que debe volver. De esas dos fechas debo obtener la cantidad de dias que hay entre esas dos fechas sin recargar la pagina y de forma dinamica y mostralas en otro input. Es posible hacer esto?.

paso los inputs por si alguno quiere ver el DOM jaja.

```
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Solicito usufructar mis vacaciones el:</label>
                              <input type="date" name="ini_vacaciones" class="form-control" required>
                              (Fecha de inicio de vacaciones)
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Hasta el</label>
                              <input type="date" name="fin_vacacaciones" class="form-control" required>
                              (fecha de finalizacion de vacaciones)
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Dias de vacaciones</label>
                              <input type="number" name="dias_vacaciones" placeholder="Dias de vacaciones" class="form-control" required>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Claro que es posible. Puedes hacerlo con Vue o jQuery por ejemplo. Revisa la librería [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Te ayudará.

Comment: Quizá esta pregunta te ayude https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22073/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-la-diferencia-de-d%C3%ADas-entre-dos-fechas-en-javascript