# Restar Fechas en JS (nuevo en js)

Tags: javascript

de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda, podrian ayudarme a resolver este simple ejercicio quiero restar dos fechas? soy nuevo con js

```
formularioCumple.addEventListener('submit',function(){

var fechaC = document.getElementById('fechaC').value;

var fechaResult = new Date();

var resultado = fechaC.getDate() - fechaResult.getDate()
});

 console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Lo intente pero no me funciono añadiendo ese script, hay alguna forma de hacerlo con js puro?

Comment: Puedes usar `DateDiff ` .
Aquí te dejo una referencia. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489500/how-do-i-subtract-one-week-from-this-date-in-jquery

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22073/52028

Answer (score -1):

Solución simple, para manipulación de fechas en JavaScript usa [momentjs.](http://momentjs.com)

```
var fecha1 = moment('2018-07-12');
var fecha2 = moment('2019-08-1');

console.log(fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'days'), ' dias de diferencia');

<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

El método [diff](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) te permite hallar la diferencia en cualquier unidad y la sintáxis es

```
moment.diff(moment, 'intervalo')
```

Para calcular lo mismo pero en horas

```
var fecha1 = moment('2018-07-12');
var fecha2 = moment('2019-08-1');

console.log(fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'hours'), ' horas de diferencia');

<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Esperó que te sirva ;).

link de referencia [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22073/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-la-diferencia-de-d%C3%ADas-entre-dos-fechas-en-javascript)

Comment: ajaja posible duplicado de pregunta y respuesta

Comment: @element en vez de estar haciendo criticas es mejor que ayudes a las demás personas a resolver sus problemas.

Comment: No se por que razón medas votos negativos :v, soy nuevo mejor ayuden a los nuevo crecer en esto, y mejorar lo.

Comment: @element lo siento, no vi, lo que hablaste solo fui directo y busque eso para la ayudar este chico, para la próxima lo tendré muy presente. Gracias!!!!

Comment: @JosueSantana si la pregunta es un duplicado la reportas como tal y no la respondes con una copia exacta la respuesta en esa pregunta

Comment: Esta respuesta es una copia de la otra y no se referencia correctamente. Sería conveniente leer [¿Cómo referenciar material escrito por otra persona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: A mi me funciona en fullcalendar aqui encontre el modo de uso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186717/moment-js-show-diff-between-2-dates    y es muy simple de usar !!!