# ¿Como puedo calcular la diferencia entre fechas sin una libreria?

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo dos fechas una de inicio y otra de retiro y necesito calcular los años transcurridos entre estas dos pero lo que pasa es que si no hay fecha de retiro se supone que los años se calcularían entre la fecha de inicio y la fecha actual y ya logre calcular los años entre la fecha de inicio y la fecha actual pero no he logrado calcular la diferencia entre la fecha de retiro y de inicio.
Esto es algo de lo que llevo

```
$(function(){
    $('#anoDeingreso').on('change', calcularPermanencia);
});
function calcularPermanencia() {

    if($("#fecha_retiro").val() === ""){

    fecha = $(this).val();
    var hoy = new Date();
    var ingreso = new Date(fecha);
    var perma = hoy.getFullYear() - ingreso.getFullYear();
    var m = hoy.getMonth() - ingreso.getMonth();

    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && hoy.getDate() < ingreso.getDate())) {
        perma--;
    }
        $('#permanencia').val(perma); 
    }else if($("#fecha_retiro").val() !== ""){

            fecha = $("#fecha_retiro").val();
            var hoy = new Date();
            var ingreso = new Date(fecha);
            var permanen = hoy.getFullYear() - ingreso.getFullYear();
            var m = hoy.getMonth() - ingreso.getMonth();

            if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && hoy.getDate() < ingreso.getDate())) {
                permanen--;
            }
            var defi = permanen - perma;
                $('#permanencia').val(defi); 
    }
}
```

Comment: En esta pregunta [¿Cómo obtener la diferencia de días entre dos fechas en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22073/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-la-diferencia-de-d%C3%ADas-entre-dos-fechas-en-javascript) puedes ver respuestas aproximadas a lo que buscas usando la librería [moment js](https://programacion.net/articulo/manejar_fechas_y_horas_como_un_profesional_con_moment_js_1301). [Aquí](https://momentjs.com/) encuentras el enlace a la pagina oficial.

Comment: Cabria la posibilidad de hacerlo sin una librería?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo obtener la diferencia de días entre dos fechas en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22073/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-la-diferencia-de-d%c3%adas-entre-dos-fechas-en-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es trabajar con dos fechas y no quieres usar librerías como `Moment`, probablemente lo que más te interesa es trabajar esas fechas en un formato en el que operar sea sencillo, por ejemplo, `Milisegundos desde el 1 de enero de 1970` de esta forma puedes operar con esas fechas de forma rápida, sencilla y sin tener que andar convirtiendo unidades.

Teniendo esto en cuenta te propongo una posible soulción:

```js
const MS_COUNT_START_YEAR = 1970; // Año desde el que se empiezan a contar las fechas en MS

const calculateYearDifference = (initDate, endDate) => {
  const initDateParsed = new Date(initDate); // Elemento Date de la fecha de inicio
  const endDateParsed = endDate ? new Date(endDate): new Date(); // Elemento date de la fecha Fin, si no se indica, es la fecha actual.
  
  const differenceInMiliseconds = endDateParsed.getTime() - initDateParsed.getTime(); // Convertimos a milisegundos ambas fechas y las restamos
  
  return new Date(differenceInMiliseconds).getFullYear() - MS_COUNT_START_YEAR; // Convertimos el resultado a fecha y obtenemos el año, restamos el año desde el que se empieza a contar y listo
}

console.log(calculateYearDifference('11-11-1992')); // Diferencia con el dia de hoy.

console.log(calculateYearDifference('11-11-1992', '10-10-1996')) // Diferencia con el 10-10-1996, 3 años.
```

Ten en cuenta que esto te devuelve los años **completos** que hayan pasado, es decir, si el cuarto año no ha transcurrido por completo el resultado será 3.