# Diferencia de Fechas entre c:out

Tags: javascript, java

solicito su apoyo ya que necesito obtener la diferencia en horas de 2 fechas

Ej:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias mostrar el codigo que llevas hecho hasta el momento?

Comment: Pensaba en implementar la fn diff de javascript pero no se como aplicarlo.

Comment: ¿Por qué pusiste la etiqueta `java` a la pregunta?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo obtener la diferencia de días entre dos fechas en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22073/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-la-diferencia-de-d%c3%adas-entre-dos-fechas-en-javascript)

Comment: Hola, Java != Javascript , Recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask], edita tu pregunta con la información que requiere la comunidad, saludos.