# Como extraer la cantidad de días entre un rango de fechas? SpreadSheep Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Como puedo hacer que con Gas me de la cantidad de días entre un rango de fechas?
Tengo este código que me he basado de restar números pero no sabría como restar campos de fechas.
Al igual que no sabría como mandarle el texto del encabezado de la columna.

```
function QuantityDays()
  {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet=ss.getSheets();
    var data=sheet[0].getDataRange().getValues();

    for(i in data)
    {
    var row=data[i];
    var DateS=row[27];
    var DateF=row[13];
    var Quantity=DateF-DateS;

    var RowStar=2 + +i;
   sheet[0].getRange(RowStar, 32).setValue(Quantity);

    }
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
```

Comment: No hace falta incluir `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` al final un script ya que el envío de los cambios hechos por el script a la hoja de cálculo se hace en automático.

Answer (score 0):

En Google Apps Script las fechas se manejan como objetos tipo `Date` de JavaScript por lo que para calcular la cantidad de días entre un par de fechas deberás usar los métodos y técnicas para este propósito basados en JavaScript.

Lo primero a tener en mente es que en JavaScript las fechas se determinan en milisegundos a partir de las 00:00:00 UTC del 1 de enero de 1970.

Considerando lo anterior la forma de hacerlo es convertir los objetos fechas a milisegundos y calcular la diferencia entre estos valores y convertir los milisegundos a días.

Cabe destacar que existen librerías de JavaScript como moment.js que incluyen métodos que hacen lo descrito anteriormente.

Para incluir una librería como moment.js en JavaScript la forma más sencilla es copiar el código de la librería en un archivo .gs en tu proyecto de Google Apps Script.

Relacionado

- [¿Cómo obtener la diferencia de días entre dos fechas en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22073/65)

Referencias

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date