# ¿Como restar fechas en javascript o con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

ya tengo mis dos fechas en formato yyyy/mm/dd pero no logro obtener la diferencia con ninguna funcion o librería, ya intentente con moment, distintas funciones etc, en la forma actual me arroja un NaN.

Ayuda, apenas estoy entendiendo a javascript :(

```js
var myDate = new Date();

var thisMonth = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(), myDate.getMonth(), 1);
var fecha2=formatDate(thisMonth);
console.log(formatDate(thisMonth));
var mes    = data[x].f_modifica.substr(6,2);
var dia    = data[x].f_modifica.substr(4,2);
var anio    = data[x].f_modifica.substr(0,4);
var fecha   = mes + '/' + dia +'/' + anio ;
var fecha1 = new Date(''+ fecha +'');
var fecha2 = new Date()
        
var resta = fecha2.getTime() - fecha1.getTime()
console.log(Math.round(resta/ (1000*60*60*24)))
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo obtener la diferencia de días entre dos fechas en JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22073/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-la-diferencia-de-d%c3%adas-entre-dos-fechas-en-javascript)

Comment: ya lo intente, me arroja que diff no es una funcion

Comment: Instalaste la libreria `Moment.js` tal y como dice la respuesta? Ese error suele salir al no tenerla instalada la puedes encontrar en la respuesta o en [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com)

Comment: Gracias pude solucionarlo!