# ¿Como puedo obtener la diferencia entre 2 fechas en ejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ejs

Como practica estoy desarrollando un crud en el cual una persona pueda ingresar 2 fechas las cuales se mostrarán en una tabla, esta es la plantilla que hice en ejs

```
<tbody>
    <% if (data) { %>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= (i+1) %></td>
                <td><%= data[i].nombre%></td>
                <td><%= moment(data[i].fecha_de_entrada).format(shortDateFormat) %></td>
                <td><%= moment(data[i].fecha_de_salida).format(shortDateFormat)%></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
     <% } %>
</tbody>
```

En la ultima celda debe estar la diferencia de dias que hay entre las 2 fechas que se ingresaron pero no se como puedo implementarlo, estoy usando moment.js para el formato de las fechas lei que puedo obtener la diferencia entre las fechas con diff() pero cuando trato de implementar este metodo en la ultima celda me salta error

Comment: ¿Cómo intentas implementarlo?

Comment: me estaba guiando de este [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22073/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-la-diferencia-de-d%C3%ADas-entre-dos-fechas-en-javascript/22079)  basicamente lo que trate de hacer es que en la celda td ponia el metodo diff pero en lugar de las variables fecha1 ponia  data[i].fecha_de_entrada para la primera fecha y data[i].fecha_de_salida para la segunda fecha

Comment: tendrias que convertirlo a moment para porder usar diff, `diff(moment(data[i].fecha_de_entrada),moment(data[i].fecha_de_salida))`

Comment: si funciono gracias!, lo puse de la siguiente manera <td><%= moment(data[i].fecha_de_salida).diff(moment(data[i].fecha_de_entrada), "days") %> dias restantes</td>