# ¿Cómo obtener la diferencia de meses, días, horas y/o minutos entre dos fechas en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

cómo podría obtener la diferencia en los valores que yo prefiera (meses, días, horas o minutos) entre dos fechas en javascript, he intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var diferencia = fecha_fin - fecha_inicio

            var dias = diferencia / 86400000 //numero es igual a los milisegundos que equivale un dia
            var horas = diferencia / 3600000 //numero es igual a los milisegundos que equivale una hora
            var minutos = diferencia / 60000 //numero es igual a los milisegundos que equivale un minuto
            var dias_truncado
            var decimal_horas
            var horas_truncado
            var decimal_minutos

            if (dias >= 1) {
                dias_truncado = Math.trunc(dias)
                decimal_horas = dias - dias_truncado
                horas = decimal_horas / 0.04166 //numero es igual a dividir 1 (dia) entre 24 (horas)

                horas_truncado = Math.trunc(horas)
                decimal_minutos = horas - horas_truncado
                minutos = decimal_minutos / 0.01666 //numero es igual a dividir 1 (hora) entre 60 (minutos)

                this.detalle_mtto.tiempo_transcurrido = dias_truncado + " días, " + horas_truncado + " horas y " + Math.round(minutos) + " minutos"
            } else if (horas >= 1) {
                horas_truncado = Math.trunc(horas) 
                decimal_minutos = horas - horas_truncado
                minutos = decimal_minutos / 0.01666 //numero es igual a dividir 1 (hora) entre 60 (minutos)
                
                this.detalle_mtto.tiempo_transcurrido = horas_truncado + " horas y " + Math.round(minutos) + " minutos"
            } else if (minutos >= 1) {
                minutos = diferencia / 60000 //numero es igual a los milisegundos que equivale un minuto
                this.detalle_mtto.tiempo_transcurrido = Math.round(minutos) + " minutos"
            } else {
                this.detalle_mtto.tiempo_transcurrido = "En segundos"
            }
```

He planteado el anterior código con mi lógica, en donde calculo la diferencia entre las dos fechas de manera normal (una resta), luego calculo los dias, horas y minutos a los cuales equivalen esta diferencia ya que la resta me devuelve un valor en milisegundos, después de ese proceso, hago validaciones para determinar si en esa diferencia hay **días**, **horas** o **minutos**; esto ya que en la diferencia de fechas puede no haber días sino horas solamente y así sucesivamente, la cuestión de todo esto es que es un algoritmo muy complejo y largo para solamente obtener la diferencia entre dos fechas, e incluso confuso de entender hasta para mí mismo. ¿Habrá algún método, librería o cualquier otra herramienta de JavaScript que me permita obtener los días, meses y minutos que hay entre dos fechas sin tanta escritura de código engorroso?

Comment: con la libreria [moment](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22075/273432) es muy simple

Comment: La he revisado y me ha sido de gran utilidad, gracias por tu información, éxitos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor opcion desde mi punto de visa es usar moment, de la forma que lo yo hago es trabajando con objetos moment

```
function edad(b) {
//Recibo un string 10-10-2021 por ejemplo
var a = moment();
//a = fecha actual como objeto moment
b = moment(b);
//Diferencia entre fechas en años
var years = a.diff(b, 'year');
//Diferencia en meses
var months = a.diff(b, 'months');
//Diferencias en dias
var days = a.diff(b, 'days');
}
```

Te dejo documentacion al respecto en el siguiente enlace : [Documentacion diff moment](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/)

Comment: No sabía acerca de esa gran herramienta, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!